# How to expose swift functions ONLY to objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a swift framework which I'm using inside an Objective C application.  I have a `Location` class that has the two params:

```
///Latitude in Decimal Degrees
public var lat : Double?

///Longitude in Decimal Degrees
public var lon : Double?
```

which are not accessible to Objective C because they are optionals.  I'm hoping to keep a swift-only class working here so my "workaround" was to add some `@objc` methods for the class as well - but I don't want them to be swift accessible.

```
///Objective C Extensions to allow easier Access
extension LocationMessage {

@objc var getLat : Double {
    if (lat != nil) {
        return lat!
    }
    return -91;
 }

@objc var getLon : Double {
    if (lon != nil) {
        return lon!;
    }
    return -181;
}
}
```

So here is the question:

1) I could put this extension into the framework but is there some way to "hide" swift from being able to call it?

2) I guess I could write a swift file into my Objective C app - that adds the extensions to the class - would that be the way to go?

3) Is there another way?

Comment: I would say that number 2 is way to go. Did you try making extension Private?

Answer (score 25):

As of Swift 3.1, this is possible using the `@available` attribute. The [official documentation on attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html) mentions a lot of different options, but doesn't make it clear how you can combine all of them. However [this Swift evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0141-available-by-swift-version.md), implemented in 3.1, discusses marking something as obsolete as of a certain version of Swift:

```
@available(swift, obsoleted: 3.1)
class Foo {
    //...
}
```

In this example, trying to use the class `Foo` in Swift 3.1 or later will give an error. With a little adjustment, we can do this:

```
@available(swift, obsoleted: 1.0)
@objc(exampleMethodWithObject:)
static func exampleMethod(with object: NSObject) {
    //...
}
```

In this example, trying to use the method `exampleMethodWithObject:` in Swift 1.0 or later will give an error, whereas using it in Objective-C will not. (If you really want to be sure, you can specify `obsoleted: 0.1`. Using `0.0` or leaving off the version number doesn't work.)

So for your code, this should work:

```
extension LocationMessage {

    @available(swift, obsoleted: 1.0)
    @objc var getLat : Double {
        if (lat != nil) {
            return lat!
        }
        return -91
    }

    @available(swift, obsoleted: 1.0)
    @objc var getLon : Double {
        if (lon != nil) {
            return lon!
        }
        return -181
    }

}
```

Comment: The 'swift' platform is only available for this attribute since swift 4. So you should use * instead ('obsoleted' argument is for swift version only so it will work)

Answer (score 6):

`@available (*, unavailable)` makes code unavailable to outward swift world, but `@objc` directive keeps it accessible by objective c.

```
@available (*, unavailable)
@objc public extension LocationMessage {

var getLat : Double {
    if (lat != nil) {
        return lat!
    }
    return -91;
 }

var getLon : Double {
    if (lon != nil) {
        return lon!;
    }
    return -181;
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work as of Xcode 12.2. The generated Objective-C header contains the SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE attribute and the method is unavailable in both languages.

Comment: @berec just checked on 12.5.1 - not working. It said `has been explicitly marked unavailable`